# Missing zero in hash of array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Does anyone know why the 0 in "1.30" doesn't show up?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

our %mb_version = (
'TXA4' => [1.30, 1.23],
);

foreach (@{$mb_version{'TXA4'}}) {
  print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1.3
1.23
```

Comment: because it's a number. trailing zeroes are not relevant and implicitly there anyways. it's like saying "my dollar is worth $1.000000000000000000000000", when `$1` is all that's really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that the version number has 2 decimal places you can do:

```
foreach (@{$mb_version{'TXA4'}}) {
  printf "%.2f\n", $_;
}
```

otherwise, you can use strings (not floats) to store version numbers.

Comment: Thanks.  I realized the string answer as well.  I just wrapped the elements in the hash of arrays with quotation marks.  Nice alternative solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Same way you can try this also....

```
foreach (@{$mb_version{'TXA4'}}) {
  sprintf("%02f", $_);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the answers suggesting formatting to two decimal places explicitly, and prefer storing version identifiers as strings, which is what they really want to be. E.g.

```
our %mb_version = (
    'TXA4' => [qw/1.30, 1.23/],
);
```